# Shader Material not working with webgl 2.0 in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am using a custom `ShaderMaterial` for a `PointCloud` in Autodesk Forge Viewer. After having gone through this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer), I was able to disable webgl2.0 for now and the code seems to work fine. But the moment I try to make it work with webGL 2.0, the shader stops working.

This is the fragment shader with webGL 2.0 turned off:

```js
 this.fragmentShader =
      options.fragmentShader ||
      `
    uniform vec3 color;
    uniform sampler2D texture;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main() {

      vec4 outColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );

      if ( outColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;
      if ( vColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;

      gl_FragColor = outColor * vec4( color * vColor.xyz, vColor.a );

    }`;
```

and the following is with webGL 2.0 and the `supportsMrtNormals` set to true for the `ShaderMaterial`

```js
this.fragmentShader =
  options.fragmentShader ||
  `
  #ifdef _LMVWEBGL2_
    #if defined(MRT_NORMALS)
      layout(location = 1) out vec4 outNormal;
      #if defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
        layout(location = 2) out vec4 outId;
        #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
          layout(location = 3) out vec4 outModelId;
        #endif
      #endif
    #elif defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
      layout(location = 1) out vec4 outId;
      #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
        layout(location = 2) out vec4 outModelId;
      #endif
    #endif
  #else
    #define gl_FragColor gl_FragData[0]
    #if defined(MRT_NORMALS)
      #define outNormal gl_FragData[1]
      #if defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
        #define outId gl_FragData[2]
        #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
          #define outModelId gl_FragData[3]
        #endif
      #endif
    #elif defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
      #define outId gl_FragData[1]
      #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
        #define outModelId gl_FragData[2]
      #endif
    #endif
  #endif
  uniform vec3 color;
  uniform sampler2D texture;

  varying vec4 vColor;

  void main() {

    vec4 outColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );

    if ( outColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;
    if ( vColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;

    gl_FragColor = outColor * vec4( color * vColor.xyz, vColor.a );

   
    #ifdef MRT_ID_BUFFER
      outId = vec4(0.0);
    #endif
    #ifdef MODEL_COLOR
      outModelId = vec4(0.0);
    #endif
    #ifdef MRT_NORMALS
      outNormal = vec4(0.0);
    #endif
  }`;
```

Comment: Can you tell me what version of the viewer you are currently using and also I assume you are trying the approach that Petr suggested without disabling Webgl 2.0 have you checked his demo - https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/custom-shader-material?

Comment: @JaimeRosales I am using viewer version 7.38. Also, in my question, I have two sets of code, the first one is with webgl 2.0 disabled and all works fine. But for the case of trying to make the same code work for webgl 2.0 fails.